# Convert DateTime to formated String on Pharo 11

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

`DateAndTime now asString` returns a string in a format like YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.s+ZZ:zz:z

Is it possible to create a String based on a DateTime but with a different format?

Comment: You will have to implement your own formatting method. The class to do that is `BasicDatePrinter`. If you need help, let us know the format(s) you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ZTimestamp for that: https://github.com/svenvc/ztimestamp